# Django app uses only default database to retrieve data. How to set the retrieve function to mysql databse

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

There are two database for my Django project. I had created function to enter data to the database (mysql), but the data used to always save in the default database. I have solved the problem now using .save(using='db2'). The current problem is that I have used instance to get the id of the user and when I want to see the user detail using the function below, the user id of the default database conflicts with the user id of the mysql database so the default databases detail is shown. How can I use only db2 like the one I used for saving data. The function for showing the userdetail is shown below.

```
DATABASES = {
'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')},

    'db2': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'subscribers',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '######',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',

}}
```

The function I created in my Django app that show the detail of user whenever requested.

```
@login_required
def userDetail(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Subscribers, id=id)
    context = {
        "Name": instance.name,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request, 'userDetail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using 'db2' change your instance to this:

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Subscribers.objects.using('db2'), id=id)
```